# Create Signed Apk for publisher APK signing

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I have an app already uploaded and published on play store. Now I want to update it. It was signed using *google-play signing*, I do have *keystore* and *cert*
but when I try to make a signed apk from android studio it gives me this error :

> Trusted certificate entries are not password-protected

I also tried to make apk using jarsigner but still on luck. 
I downloaded certificate then added certificate in jks but still there is error.

```
Certificate chain not found for: mykey.  mykey must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
```

mykey is valid key I can see it in keystore List

Comment: I suspect your entry in the keystore contains just the certificate but not the private key. Do you still have the original keystore that was used to sign the first APK you uploaded to the play console?

Comment: some one send me keystore and said its original. same as you i also have doubt that this jks has certificate added in it. because alias entry Type is trustedCertEntery

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Keystore is not the certificate that Google gives you once you upload the app on the Google App store, the Keystore is the one that Android Studio gives you once you sign the app, it requires an Alias and a Password too to be more precise, however, try to find the Keystore because you can't update your own app without the SAME Keystore you used for the first upload, good luck and keep coding, let me know if you need more support or if you still have some doubt, have a good day!